# Using built-in SQL functions with SequelizeJS

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

Can I make Sequelize JS to include combined field to the result set, to get results like for following query?

```
SELECT id, NOW()-timestamp as recordAge FROM myTable
```

I wouldn't use raw query for this task, prefer to resolve it with model paradigm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As there was no answer but someone has starred my question I'm posting the answer I've found myself:

The solution is to use ***Sequelize.literal()*** function. As for example in the question, the answer is following:

```
options = {};
options.attributes = ['id', sequelize.literal('(NOW() - timestamp) as recordAge')];
MyTable.find(options).success(success);
```